# What is a native peer?

Tags: java, terminology

Native peer is defined in Effective Java (2nd) as following

> A second legitimate use of finalizers concerns objects with native peers. *A **native peer** is a **native object** to which a **normal object delegates** via **native methods**.* Because a **native peer is not a normal object**, the garbage collector doesn’t know about it and can’t reclaim it when its **Java peer** is reclaimed.

In another question [java peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568972/what-is-a-native-object) is explained with example. Is it the java class `PrintHello` or another class which uses `PrintHello`?

What part is being called a Native Peer here and which part is Java Peer, any example? I understand the use of finalize, I am only confused about which part native peer is being referred to.

Comment: @DimaSan I linked to this exact question and it does not explain native peer.

Comment: @DimaSan It's actually the reverse of that question, though the top answer does also answer this question.

Comment: That quote already explains what a native peer is ("a native object to which a normal object delegates via native methods"), what is unclear about that quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example would be a native window vs. a `JFrame`. A `JFrame` is a Java peer, but it needs a (platform dependent) native peer to actually display graphics.

This is why you need to call `dispose()` when getting rid of a `JFrame`. You need to get rid of the native component explicitly, because the GC can't touch it.

Comment: It's the native component of the thing you're using. As opposed to the Java part. Are you just getting confused because of the naming?

Comment: So in the linked question, `print_hello` class is the native peer, correct?

Answer (score 3):

A native object is not programmed only in java, but in a platform specific language, typically c or assembler.

Memory allocated by this code cannot be disposed by the GC. Therefore you may need to clean it in a finalizer.

The native peer is the native part of a Java object.

You can see a nice example here:
https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077520/learn-java/java-tip-23--write-native-methods.html

Comment: I know what is a native object. I don't know what is a native peer.

Comment: It's the native part of an object

Comment: Native part of an object or the code? i.e. `public native void printText ();` or `void Happy_printText (struct HHappy *this) {...}`